# String builder within IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table called `PostUnitManagers` and it provides a many to many relationship between `Post` and `Unit` tables.

I'd like to display a list of Unit Mangers which would display the Post Name with a list of Units that they manage.

I had the thought to use a `StringBuilder` to create a Units list like that:

> Post 1 Manages: Unit 1, Unit 2, Unit 3
>
> Post 2 Manages: Unit 4, Unit 5, Unit 6 etc.

As I'm still new to this I'm at a loss as to how to go about it and have reached a dead end.

I currently have the following controller to get a list of PostUnitManagers but this doesn't create the Units list

```
        public ActionResult UnitManagersList()
    {
        var records = db.PostUnitManagers;

        var viewModel = records.Select(t => new ListUnitManagersViewModel
        {
             PostName = t.Post.PostName,
             //Units = StringBuilder of all units they have a record in PostUnitMangers Table
        });

        return PartialView("_UnitManagersList", viewModel);
    }
```

PostUnitMangers Class

```
    public class PostUnitManager
{
    public int PostUnitManagerId { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use String.Format? :) imo it's more readable...

Comment: Use the [string.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) method for you wanting to convert the collection to a coma separated string

Comment: I'm happy to use anything that will do the job, the issue is I currently don't have the knowledge to know how to implement them within the code

Comment: Another option: get just a list of all units (as a list of Unit objects) and let the view create the presentation.

Comment: Would anyone be able to post some example code? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have a collection `PostUnitManagers` of `PostUnitManager` objects similar to:

```
class PostUnitManager
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

If this is the case, you need to group your initial collection by `Post` value (I assume they override `Equals` method):

```
var grouped = db.PostUnitManagers.GroupBy(q => q.Post).ToArray();
```

Then you need to extract Unit values that are grouped under specific `Post`:

```
var result = grouped.Select(q => new ListUnitManagersViewModel() 
    {
         PostName = q.Key.PostName,
         Units = String.Join(", ", q.Select(w => w.Unit.UnitName))
    });
```

Comment: thanks @slawekin that makes sense but I do have errors on Unit.UnitName and Post.PostName saying that the grouping doesn't contain a definition for Post or Unit?

Comment: The amendment sorts the PostName but the same issue still occurs on the UnitName

Comment: does `Unit` class have `UnitName` property? adjust it's name to fit what you need the result you mentioned in the question come from

Comment: It does, the only available option after w is Key which then only gives access to the Post class

Comment: it compiles fine for me in this version, please check if you have copied it correctly (mostly q and w variables)

Comment: Thats fixed the issue my typo. However in the view all I get is a comma and no unit names displayed

Comment: Fixed the issue by adding toArray on the grouped variable and changing to String.Join

Comment: yes, it was supposed to be String.Join, my bad. ToArray is not required, though, at least as far as linq is concerned